# asp.net core - Set Serilog.Exceptions from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog, serilog-exceptions

I need to use Serilog.Exceptions package to catch exceptions.
Serilog is read from appsettings.json

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [
            "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile",
            "Serilog.Sinks.Seq"
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "RollingFile",
                "Args": {
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
                    "pathFormat": "myPath\\log-{Date}.log"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "RollingFile",
                "Args": {
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
                    "pathFormat": "myPath\\error-{Date}.log"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Seq",
                "Args": {
                    "serverUrl": "myUrl",
                    "apiKey": "myApiKey"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [
            "FromLogContext",
            "WithMachineName",
            "WithThreadId"
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "myApplicationName"
        }
    }
}
```

And in my **startup.cs**

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Logger = logger;
```

But it doesn't work. Do I need to add some other properties in appsettings.json for Serilog.Exceptions package? Or is the appsettings.json configure correctly? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is how I setup `Serilog` in `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. You can take it as checklist and see what you have missed.

1. Install packages from Nuget: `Serilog.AspNetCore`, `Serilog.Exceptions`, `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` and other sinks you want to use.
2. Setup `Serilog` in your main program:

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => 
                   loggerConfiguration
                       .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
               );
   }
   ```
3. Put `WithExceptionDetails` in your `Serilog` section in `appsettings.json`:

   ```
   {
       "Serilog": {
           ...
           "Enrich": [
               "FromLogContext",
               "WithExceptionDetails"
           ],
           ...
       }
   }
   ```